# Drupal 8 File Upload error: Could not move uploaded File

Tags: file-upload, drupal, drupal-8

I have created a new content type, and all of a sudden I can not upload any images to my site. It is a local server so disk space is not an issue.

The error is

> The file could not be saved because the upload did not complete.
>
> File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.
>
> This value should not be null."

It is drupal 8.1.8

I have changed the temp directory to a place that www-data has full read and write permissions, as well as changing the files folder to 777, none of which seem to fix the issue.

There isn't even any apache errors that are being thrown, the only error is in drupal logs and on the page

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJDeg.png)

Comment: any solution? I face the same issue

Answer (score 1):

on drupal root directory try

```
 sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t sites/default/files
```

Answer (score 0):

See the folder premissions here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions. This is a common folder permissions issue.

Comment: The question is for Drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem on (Laragon, Drupal 9 & Windows 10) by changing the PHP from NTS to Thread Safe.